# How to inject javascript code with ADB in a browser open tab?

Tags: javascript, android, adb

I'm in the process of creating an Android test farm system, and while at it, I'm trying to find a way to inject javascript in an already open tab in the default browser.

I'm trying with

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "javascript:alert('Hello world!');" -n com.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity
```

and while it works, it opens in a new tab.

Is there any way to do it in the current tab?

Answer (score 0):

If you're cool with using Chrome, which is the default browser for newer versions of Android, you can use Chrome's [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging).

Once you've enabled this on the device (enable usb debugging + web debugging), you can connect by executing:

`adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote`

If you hit localhost:9222 from your browser, you'll see the chrome dev tools for each one of your tabs. From here, you can do anything you could usually do in the desktop chrome inspector, including executing JavaScript from the console.

If this is not automated enough, you can write an app that uses a WebView, configure it to handle an intent where you provide arbitrary JavaScript, and use `webview.loadUrl(js)` to execute it.